# android - java.lang.StackOverflowError in Titanium app

Tags: android, titanium, stack-overflow

I have a titanium app for Android and IOS. The app is complex, because it load different modules. I mean, I have a view, and in the top of the view I load a module with other components, in the middle another module with a webview and in the bottom another module with buttons.

If I load this view inside my app it works ok. But I want to create a scrollable view and add the same view with different parameters. Like this:

```
var scrollableView = Ti.UI.createScrollableView({
    views : [new MyView("View 1", "red"), new MyView("View 2", "green"), new MyView("View 3", "blue")],
    showPagingControl : true
});
```

When I tried this (adding the view only once), I have a java.lang.StackOverflowError.

Here is the [log](http://pastebin.com/qeDTZyqM)

Do you know what could be the reason? The view works well but when I add it inside a scrollableview, app stop unexpectedly.

Do you know how I can know where is the problem?

Thanks in advance

**UPDATE**

I enclose the problem, but I don't understand.

I found that the problem is when I add some components views and a module. I simplify how I add these components and I've found when it works and when it doesn't work.

This code works:

```
var topCircleViewPortrait = Ti.UI.createView({
    height : utils.getTopCircleHeight(),
    width : view.width,
    top : 0,
    backgroundColor : "transparent"
});

var scrollView = Ti.UI.createScrollView({
    contentWidth : 'auto',
    showHorizontalScrollIndicator : true,
    height : '100%',
    width : '100%',
    scrollType : 'horizontal',
    left : 0,
    right : 0
});

topCircleViewPortrait.add(scrollView);

var circulo = Circular_graph.Constructor(circularGraphs, 'IB', '#cf1022', '#960913', '#960913');
circulo.update('80', '80', '50', 1);

scrollView.add(circulo);

view.add(topCircleViewPortrait);
```

However, I want to add more "Circular_graph" to my scroll view, so I tried to create a view with layout horizontal, add the different "Circular_graphs" to this view and then, add this view to my scroll view. It doesn't work.

This is the code that doesn't work:

```
var topCircleViewPortrait = Ti.UI.createView({
    height : utils.getTopCircleHeight(),
    width : view.width,
    top : 0,
    backgroundColor : "transparent"
});

var scrollView = Ti.UI.createScrollView({
    contentWidth : 'auto',
    showHorizontalScrollIndicator : true,
    height : '100%',
    width : '100%',
    scrollType : 'horizontal',
    left : 0,
    right : 0
});

topCircleViewPortrait.add(scrollView);

var circularGraphs = Ti.UI.createView({
    height : parent.height,
    width : Titanium.UI.SIZE,
    backgroundColor : "transparent"
});

var circulo = Circular_graph.Constructor(circularGraphs, 'IB', '#cf1022', '#960913', '#960913');
circulo.update('80', '80', '50', 1);

circularGraphs.add(circulo);
scrollView.add(circularGraphs);

view.add(topCircleViewPortrait);
```

Comment: Could you provide the code of your **Circular_graph** ? And just a remark, I don't see any **layout: horizontal** in your ScrollView...

Comment: I've tried your code with the **layout: 'horizontal'** property set, I have created views instead of your **Circular_graph**, and the horizontal scroll works like a charm :)